# Ряд Тейлора, разложение, общий член

Tags: математика, ряды

Пытаюсь разложить ряд 1/sqrt(x+1) в ряд Тейлора. Вики говорит, что формула для sqrt(1+x) [image: формула]

Т.к. 1/sqrt(x+1) = (sqrt(x+1))^-1, то я попытался перевернуть дробь на картинке и посчитать члены ряда, но оказалось, что формула вышла неверной. Подскажите, что не так.

Comment: "но оказалось, что формула вышла неверной" - уточните

Comment: при суммировании не выходит число, которое я получил с помощью компьютера

Comment: Так покажите, *как* вы считаете число с помощью компьютера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вобщем, смотрите на формулу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подставляйте  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]  и считайте... Тем более что запись в таком виде заставит вас считать эффективнее, так как, как мне кажется, вы наверняка считали (2n)!, (n!)<sup>2</sup>, 4<sup>n</sup> и иже с ними, а потом собирали в один член. Т.е. действовали наиболее неверным способом...

Comment: Реализовал, все заработало как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Bот что не так:

```
[a + b] != [1 / (1 / a + 1 / b)]
```

или

```
[1 / a + 1 / b] != [1 / (a + b)]
```

Вам надо переворачивать не каждый член, а конечный результат вычисления суммы.

---

***Число, обратное сумме нескольких слагаемых, не равно сумме чисел, обратных этим слагаемым.***

> *Такова тема в упрощенном виде. Я бы сделал из нее два таких тома, как
>   этот, - добавил иезуит.* Дюма "Три мушкетера"

Comment: Разве 1/sqrt(1+x)!=(sqrt(1+x))^(-1)?

Comment: @HideME Это-то верно - справа и слева разные записи одного и того же.

Comment: не понял, что неверно в формуле общего вида, если ее перевернуть(как бы возвести в минус 1 степень)

Comment: 8 = 2+2+2+2. Но почему-то 1/8 не хочет быть равна 1/2+1/2+1/2+1/2...

Comment: @HideME Не используйте в математике слово "как бы".

Comment: @Harry *как бы*  не хочет

Comment: @igor но это же правильно, возведение в минус первую степень переворачивает дробь